# One Outlet for multiple route Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I'm working with AngularJS 2 routes. I have one layout with fixed header and dynamic sidebar and dynamic content. I have created following routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
        { path: '', component: HeaderComponent, outlet: 'header' },
        { path: '', component: SidebarComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' },
        { path: '', component: ContentComponent, outlet: 'content' },
        { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, outlet: 'content' }
    ], 
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
];
```

When I visit to my home page i.e. http://localhost/ it works fine. Currently what I need is for profile page only my content outlet should change keeping same header and sidebar content as my home page.
Main thing is when I visit to /profile page it should show the same header and sidebar content and only content which is inside content outlet should change and should show my profile content data.

I have created following routerLink

```
[routerLink]="['/profile']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving **/profile** as a children of **ContentComponent**.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: HeaderComponent, outlet: 'header' },
    { path: '', component: SidebarComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' },
    { path: '', component: ContentComponent, outlet: 'content'
      children: [
        { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent }
      ]
    },
  ]},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
];
```

EDIT 1

Maybe you can try to create a **LayoutComponent** in which you can have the named outlets and a generic outlet for your template.

something like:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: HeaderComponent, outlet: 'header' },
      { path: '', component: SidebarComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' },
      { path: '', component: ContentComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
          { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];


// LayoutComponent template
<router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Getting this error: 
More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
Conflicting components: ProfileComponent,ContentComponent. Since, both  should render html based on the url, so I have given both the same selector i.e. <app-content></app-content>. Any way to fix this ?

Comment: Please check the updated response, hope it helps. Also here is the official guide on routing: https://angular.io/guide/router